# How does chat applications sync chats while the chat fragment is open

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to sync chat converstation while the converstation is open.
What is the best way to do it?
Today I load the converstation when opening it - I have async task that send get request to server, get json array of messages as response and show it to user, how can I reload the converstation when the user got message.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use GCM (or other) push services.
2. Let the client ask every x seconds if there's something new.

That's about it :)

Comment: So if I got intent I should check if it's relevantic to my converstation and update the chat?

Comment: @LiorPozin You should of course only push messages to the relevant devices. How that is done is up to the implementation of the backend.